# How to execute multiple key actions using webdriver with java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

This is my code that opens a webpage and feeds input text into textfield and tries to browse further automatically. The first code: element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER); is working but the next two lines immediately after this have no effect in my program. I am stuck here. Pls help me

```
public class GoogleSuggest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();

        // And now use this to visit Google
        driver.get("http://www.google.com");

        // Find the text input element by its name
        WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));

        // Enter something to search for
        element.sendKeys("vtu results");

        element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

        element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
        element.sendKeys(Keys.Enter);


        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());

        // Google's search is rendered dynamically with JavaScript.
        // Wait for the page to load, timeout after 10 seconds

        (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
            public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
                return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("v");
            }
        });

        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    }
}
```

Comment: Um, what are you trying to do? If you physically press `enter` in the google search field it will submit the form and transfer your client (automated or not) to a new page.

Comment: Use sleep after each of the commands: element.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);
element.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
element.sendKeys(Keys.Enter); and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Not clear what all actions you want perform but following working for me.
Try this out:

```
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.name("q"));
    Actions action = new Actions(driver);
    element.sendKeys("result");
    action.sendKeys(element,Keys.ENTER).perform();
    action.sendKeys(Keys.TAB);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).perform();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
    (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10)).until(new ExpectedCondition<Boolean>() {
        public Boolean apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("R");
        }
    });

    System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
}
```

Comment: d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("R"); should be d.getTitle().toLowerCase().startsWith("r"); right?